# CV: dates and location on the same line

Tags: cv, line

i am trying to put the date and location on the same line on my CV as shown in the following pictures

Mine:

[image: Mine]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Please add a compilable minimal working example code to your question. Without knowing which of the trillion different CV styles you use, it is really difficult to come up with an answer which will work for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.